# Run Executable from Powershell script with parameters

Tags: powershell, command-line

So I have a powershell script that is supposed to run an executable with an argument to pass to set which method I want to run, and I need to pass a parameter, which is a directory to a config file. So this is what I have

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\test.exe" -ArgumentList /genmsi/f $MySourceDirectory\src\Deployment\Installations.xml
```

/f is the shortname and file is the long name for my attribute... I get an error in powershell telling me that a positional parameter cannot be found for /f or /file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @sebagomez I found this reddit post about the above link: https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/28zc0w/external_commands_done_right_blogedgylogic/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet.

```
Invoke-Expression "& `"$scriptPath`" test -r $number -b $testNumber -f $FileVersion -a $ApplicationID"
```

Answer (score 63):

Try quoting the argument list:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\test.exe" -ArgumentList "/genmsi/f $MySourceDirectory\src\Deployment\Installations.xml"
```

You can also provide the argument list as an array (comma separated args) but using a string is usually easier.

Answer (score 29):

Here is an alternative method for doing multiple args.  I use it when the arguments are too long for a one liner.

```
$app = 'C:\Program Files\MSBuild\test.exe'
$arg1 = '/genmsi'
$arg2 = '/f'
$arg3 = '$MySourceDirectory\src\Deployment\Installations.xml'

& $app $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to move this logic in a loop?

Answer (score 8):

Just adding an example that worked fine for me:

```
$sqldb = [string]($sqldir) + '\bin\MySQLInstanceConfig.exe'
$myarg = '-i ConnectionUsage=DSS Port=3311 ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword= ' + $rootpw
Start-Process $sqldb -ArgumentList $myarg
```