# powershell to pass parameter not working correctly

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am having an issue with a powershell script. The script set parameter and tries to execute a .bat file passing in the parameters.

```
$app='test.bat';
$appLoc='C:\scripts';
$arg1='userid';
$arg2='password';    
$arg3='filelocation';
$arg= $arg1 + $arg2 + $arg3;

Set-Location $appLoc;
```

I have tried everything to run the batch script passing in the parameters using

```
& $app $arg

& $app -ArgumentList $arg

Start-Process $app -ArgumentList $arg -wait -passthru

& $app $arg1 $arg2 $arg3
```

All four statements above is failing. It looks like it is only executing the batch script and not passing in the parameters.

Comment: Is it really like that `$app=test.bat;` without any quotes?

Comment: `$app=test.bat` is running the batch file right away, unless it's in the current folder then it's throwing an error. `$arg1=userid;` is not valid powershell, it's an error (or it's running a command called 'userid'?). `-ArgumentList` takes a list (array) and you're passing it a string. Please edit to include some actual code that demonstrates what you're doing and what's going wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo of working code:

## Batch File "c:\temp\psbat.bat"

```
@echo off
echo one %1
echo two %2
```

## PowerShell File "c:\temp\psbat.ps1"

```powershell
Push-Location 'c:\temp\'
& '.\psbat.bat' 1 2
Pop-Location
```

## Output

```
one 1
two 2
```

## Powershell (with variables)

Amending the powershell above to use variables, we find it still works:

```powershell
Push-Location 'c:\temp\'
$app = '.\psbat.bat'
$arg1 = 'argument 1'
$arg2 = 2
&$app $arg1 $arg2
Pop-Location
```

## Why yours isn't working

If you run the above example without the quotes, the batch file gets executed, and the output is returned to `$app`.  So `$app` gets the value:

`one
two`

When PS tries to later execute `$app`, it tries to run those PS commands; and since `one` and `two` aren't commands, it fails with an error such as:

```
& : The term 'one  two  ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options. Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187048/run-executable-from-powershell-script-with-parameters). It is an answer to run exes in general.

You can put your parameters in an array and pass them to the bat:

```
$app = 'test.bat'
$args = @()    
$args += 'userid'
$args += 'password'
$args += 'filelocation'

& $app $args
```