# Incorporating %USERNAME% Variable in PowerShell PS1 Script For Creating Nuget Packages

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

```
nuget pack C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Source\Repos\Common\Common\Common.nuspec -OutputDirectory D:\NugetFeed
```

The above code is what is in my nugetpack.ps1 file. It works perfectly when I directly enter my username is the path, but I need it to be able to work for multiple users. I entered the %USERNAME% username variable into the path but I get the following response:

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Source.....'.

How can I use the %USERNAME% variable in my path. I am new to PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables in PowerShell are on the logical drive `env:`, but are otherwise syntactically normal PowerShell variables. The use of `%...%` is BATCH syntax. For PowerShell, use `$env:varname`, e.g., `$env:username`.

You may also find that you need the information in "[Run Executable From PowerShell Script With Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187048/run-executable-from-powershell-script-with-parameters)".